# AWS Fail Step Function in case of Lambda Failure, and still send Error Object in response

Tags: amazon-web-services, error-handling, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Problem Statement: I have 2 Lambdas in a State Machine, and I want the State Machine Invocation to FAIL in case of a Failure in any Lambda function. In case of Failure, I want the stateMachine to FAIL, and send the ERROR Object back in terms of
`{"cause":"...", "error":"..."}`

I am able to catch the error by introducing a state, and send it back. But, AWS is marking the StepFunction invocation as a SUCCESS. I want it to be marked as FAIL.

AS-IS: I have the stateMachine sitting behind an API Gateway, with methods "startExecution" & "DescribeExecution" defined in the Gateway

PS: I've already gone through this
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-handling-error-conditions.html

Thanks in advance, any help much appreciated